# Django Tastypie : How to initiate a variable every time an api call is made?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, tastypie

I have two models :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    sex =  models.CharField(choices=SEX, blank=True, max_length=5) 
    name = models.TextField(blank=True) 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category) 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

I'm creating an api using tastypie that returns me "SubCategory" objects in a JSON. I want to add a custom field "start_counter_of_category" in every result set which contains the counter of the subcategory where the category id changed (when ordered on "category_id" field)

The algorithm is fairly straightforward, something like this in the "dehydrate" function:

```
API_SKU_VARS = {
    'COUNTER'       : 1,
    'FIRST_ELEMENT' : 1,
    'PREV_CATEGORY' : 1
}


class SubCategoryResource(ModelResource):
    start_counter_of_category = fields.IntegerField(readonly=True)
    category = fields.ForeignKey(CategoryResource,'category')
    class Meta:
        queryset = SubCategory.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'subcategory'
        filtering = {
            'id' : ALL,
            'name' : ALL,
            'category': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
        ordering = ['id','name','category']
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        if API_SKU_VARS['PREV_CATEGORY']  != bundle.data['category']: #if the category of the current bundle is not equal to the category of the previous bundle, we update the ['PREV_CATEGORY'] 
            API_SKU_VARS['FIRST_ELEMENT']=API_SKU_VARS['COUNTER'] #update the ['FIRST_ELEMENT'] with the counter of the current bundle
            API_SKU_VARS['PREV_CATEGORY'] = bundle.data['category']
        API_SKU_VARS['COUNTER'] = API_SKU_VARS['COUNTER']+1 #for every bundle passed, we update the counter
        bundle.data['start_counter_of_category']=API_SKU_VARS['FIRST_ELEMENT']
        return bundle.data
    serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
```

It works perfectly for the first run after I start the server. Predictably the issue of course is that the second time I make the api call, the variables retain the values they had in the previous run.

Any ideas how to re-initiate the variables every time the api call is made?

**SOLUTION:**

re-initialte the variables in

- **build_filters** if the api called is a filtering API
- **get_detail** if the api called is a detail API

example (in my case):

```
def build_filters(self, filters=None):
        if filters is None:
            filters = {}
        orm_filters = super(SubCategoryResource, self).build_filters(filters) #get the required response using the function's behavior from the super class
        self.API_SKU_VARS = {
            'PREV_CATEGORY':1,
            'COUNTER':1,
            'FIRST_ELEMENT':1,
        }
        return orm_filters
```

(These functions are over-ridden if you want to apply any custom logic into the API response)

**BETTER AND MOST OBVIOUS SOLUTION**

re-instantiate the variables in the ***init*** function, something like this:

```
def __init__(self,api_name=None):
    self.API_SKU_VARS = {.....}
    super(SKUResource,self).__init__(api_name)
```

Comment: Global variables is bad design, specially for a language with nice namespaces like Python.

Comment: @PauloScardine Probably my question was a little wrong, I do not want the variable to be global. I need to re-initialize the value of the variables every time I make the API call.

Comment: If you don't want the variable to be global, don't define it at global scope. Figure out what object represents the right thing and has the right lifetime (it's probably the `SubCategoryResource` instance), and create API_SKU_VARS as a member of that object (e.g., by setting `self.API_SKU_VARS` in the `__init__` method).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reinitialize (not "reinitiate") the variables just by running this code at the start of each call:

```
API_SKU_VARS['COUNTER'] = 1
API_SKU_VARS['PREV_CATEGORY'] = 1
API_SKU_VARS['FIRST_ELEMENT'] = 1
```

But this is a bad idea. Why is this variable global in the first place? The whole point of a global variable is that it's shared by all objects in the module, and lives for the lifetime of the module. If you want something that's local to a single API call and lives for the lifetime of that call, make it a member of something that has those characteristics. Initialize the member as part of initializing the appropriate object. Then there's no need to reinitialize it.

To see why this is a bad idea: What happens if two clients connect up concurrently and both make the same API call?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very valid doubt made in the end. Yes, that is a huge problem. But, my current scenario does not demand concurrency. Still it will be great to know how to efficiently do it in case of concurrent users too.  

Coming to the reinitialization of the variable, this is what I'm not able to make out specifically in the tastypie module where to do the reinitialization. Tried doing this in the resources.py file but that does not work.

Comment: If you don't want concurrency, why are you writing a web service at all? Why not just write a script to run locally, and toss all the unnecessary complexity? It's pretty much a given that anything that has to go online has to handle concurrency. At any rate, the way to handle member variables efficiently is to make them member variables instead of trying to fake them with globals. But efficiency is just a side effect here; the reason to do it the right way isn't that it's a tiny bit faster, but that it actually works.